# JS Music player does not work in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am trying to use Music Player in http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/06/html-music-player/. 
But I have modified the code in such a way that it collects the data from AJAX. (Slim PHP) like

```
myPlaylist[j] = {


                        mp3: 'music/demo_songs/'+data.tasks[j].demo_song,
                        //oga: 'music/5.ogg',
                        title: data.tasks[0].album_name+'-'+data.tasks[j].song_name,
                        artist: data.tasks[0].music_director,
                        rating: '3',
                        //buy:'addtocart.php?song_id='+data.tasks[j].song_id+'&album_id='+data.tasks[j].album_id+'&base_url_al='+window.location.href,
                        buy:'addtocart.php?song_id='+data.tasks[j].song_id+'&album_id='+data.tasks[j].album_id,
                        price: data.tasks[j].price,
                        duration: data.tasks[j].demo_song_duration,
                        cover: 'images/albums/'+data.tasks[j].album_img};
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.music-single').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
        currencySymbol:'<del>&#2352;</del>',
        buyText:'Add to Cart',
        tracksToShow:3,
        ratingCallback:function(index, playlistItem, rating){
            //some logic to process the rating, perhaps through an ajax call
        },
        jPlayer:{
            swfPath:'../../../www.jplayer.org/2.1.0/js'
        },
        autoPlay:false

    });
    });
```

When I run in chrom the code works perfectly fine and I am able to see the player with the list of songs. But the same When I open in Firefox I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: a is undefined


...},setMedia:function(a){var c=this,d=!1,e=this.status.media.poster!==a.poster;thi...


jquery.jplayer.js (line 64, col 194)
```

Not really sure about the problem. Can any one help..